# Replace class containing footer with nothing

Tags: regex, notepad++

In Notepad++, what regex would I have to use to replace class containing footer tag with nothing? I have over 500 of these tags, so regex would be useful!

From this:

```
<footer class="px-stream-post__footer" >
...content
</footer>
```

To:

```
Nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

In Notepad++, Find and Replace Window, select Regular Expression option and select `. matches newline`

Find what: `<(footer)\s*.*\>[^<]*<\/\1>\r*\n*`

Replace:

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/B7f5NA/1)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to go, it deals with embeded tags:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `<(footer)\b((?!</\1>).)*</\1>\R?`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- *CHECK `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
<(footer)        : start tag, capture group 1
\b               : word boundary
(                : start capture group 2
  (?!</\1>)      : negative lookahead, make sure we don't have a closing tag
  .              : 1 any character, including line break
)*               : group 2 may appear 0 or more times
</\1>            : close tag
\R?              : optional line break
```